# Create a RAID1 Mirror After OS and apps have been installed

Tags: raid1, mirroring

We are building a server but one of the new disks is dead on arrival. If we put the os and apps etc on the first disk, when we get the bad disk replaced can any one see any reason we shouldn't be able to create a Raid 1 Mirror at that point?

Comment: If all else fails, would you be able to afford enough down-time to take an image of the drive, create the array and restore the image? It's the safest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to make a RAID-1 volume after installation using Windows software RAID. Assuming you're using Windows there's no reason to delay installation on account of the RAID.

Linux software RAID is a little more tricky to migrate into after installation but it's still feasible. It's going to depend on your distribution as to the procedure.

If you're using some other OS besides those two please update your question.

Comment: And if you're building a hardware RAID, it depends on the details of the adapter's capabilities.

Comment: We're going to use hardware raid (i dont really like using software based raid solutions), i've done some more investigation and it looks like the adapter will support it